# What happen when you call an override method using super and this keyword?

Tags: java, this, super

```
public class Superclass {



    void method0(){
        System.out.println("superclass");
    }
}


public class Subclass extends Superclass{

    void method0(){
        System.out.println("subclass");
    }

    void method1(){
        super.method0();
    }

    void method2(){
        this.method0();
    }
}


public class RunClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Subclass().method1();
        new Subclass().method2();
    }
}
```

the code above print out

```
superclass
superclass
```

while I expect it to print out

```
superclass
subclass
```

Isn't **this.method0()** refer to the method0 in subclass and print out **subclass** instead of **superclass**?

Comment: it's working for me:
superclass
subclass

Comment: It prints out `superclass subclass` for me

Comment: Unless you are hiding some code , this seems impossible !!!

Comment: its working fro me as well. superclass and subclass

Comment: Same here, looks and works fine. prints 'superclass subclass'.

Comment: Have a look here [Your code @ Ideone](http://ideone.com/mhLwQg). It prints whats expected out of it! Recheck your output again.

Comment: it work. sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super` represents the instance of parent class.
`this` represents the instance of current class.
It will print 
superclass
subclass

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it gaves me

```
superclass
subclass
```

this what should printed every thing seems ok

Answer (score 0):

```
new Subclass().method1();
```

executes the `method1()` of `Subclass` instance, which in turn calls `super.method0();` i.e parent class instance's `method0()` i.e. `Superclass` instance `method0()`.

```
new Subclass().method2();
```

executes the `method2()` of `Subclass` instance, which in turn calls `this.method0();` i.e this instance's `method0()` i.e. `Subclass` instance `method0()`.

`super` is used to access instance members of the parent class while `this` is used to access members of the current class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it prints out the what you are expecting.

Second,

> Isn't this.method0() refer to the method0 in subclass and print out
>   subclass instead of superclass?

`this` => refer to current object, using it you can use it (kinda of pointer to itself, in general terms )

`super` => refer to super class object in an hierarchy, usually used to access the hidden members in subclass